# Populate a blank column with another column using two other columns on two separate tabs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have one spreadsheet with two tabs. MTD Revenue contains a column for District and a column for Contract #. MTD Costs has a column for contract # and I've added a column for district. Is there a formula I could use where the blank district column is auto populated using the contract # and district columns from the MTD Revenue tab. The link to the two tabs would be the contract #.[MTD Revenue Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJwQ2.jpg)[MTD Costs Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcSOK.jpg)

In all of the other formulas I've seen on here the user specifies what the output should be. I want what is actually in the district column to come over to the MTD Costs tab. For instance, in the screen shots, ST-544B49-01 is found on both tabs. On the MTD Revenue, ST-544B49-01 has Amite in the District Column. I want that record to come over to the MTD Cost tab under District.

My first thought was to use a vlookup in the empty column`=VLOOKUP(B2,'MTD Revenue'!A:K,1,FALSE)` This gives a value is not available to the formula or function error.

My second thought was to use index and match in the empty column`=INDEX('MTD Revenue'!A2:A503,MATCH('MTD Costs'!B2,'MTD Revenue'!F2:F503))`.  This only populates some of the cells and give a value is not available to the formula or function error.

I'm not the greatest formula writer so I think I'm close but am writing the formula wrong or I'm missing a piece.

I can provide the data if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by *This only populates some of the cells* for your INDEX/MATCH formula (that seems correct at first sight). Also it looks like you have actual tables. So you might want to consider using table references.

Comment: Please check this:[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would help to have a sample data from your real problem to easier reproduce it. You can use this tool: [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) to provide the data in table markdown format, so we can copy and paste from your question to an excel testing file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work using the formula below

```
=INDEX('MTD Revenue'!A:A,MATCH('MTD Costs'!B2,'MTD Revenue'!F:F))
```